# How do you use SoundManager for multiple player games over the network?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, sound, audio, unity-networking

I have created a basic sound manager according to this unity tutorial (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike/audio). However, I need it to work for multiple players over the network, and it doesn't make sense for them all to be playing the same sounds. E.g. If a player loses, it should play the gameover sound, but the other player(s) should remain in the game and continue playing the game sound. But the current behavior is that once a player loses, everyone gets the gameover sound.

By the tutorial, I currently use a single instance within the SoundManager class. I think I need multiple SoundManager instances, each associated with a client. What's the best thing to attach the SoundManagers too? Or is there a different best practice for managing sounds for multi-player games?

Here's the code for my sound manager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static SoundManager instance = null; 

    public AudioSource effects;
    public AudioSource music;

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy (gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }

    public void playSoundEffect(AudioClip clip) {
        effects.PlayOneShot (clip, 1f);
    }

    public void setBackgroundMusic(AudioClip clip) {
        music.clip = clip;
        music.Play ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be much easier than I imagined. Don't know if this is a best practice, but you can just attach the sound manager to an empty game object and get a client instance of it via `GameObject.Find("Name of your sound manager").GetComponent<SoundManager>()`. You can do this inside of `public override void OnStartLocalPlayer ()`. Get rid of the instance variable inside the class.